# How can I make a HTML ID go outside of my container?

Tags: html, css, tags, position, overflow

I have a container @ 900px width and then inside that I have an header at 100% width but it only takes 100% of the container, how can I make it take the whole entire page and ignore the container without taking it out of the container html tags?

```
#container {
width: 900px;
margin: auto;
padding: auto;
position: relative;
}

#header {
background-image: url(pat.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
height: 150px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sample code would be nice. Sight unseen, I really don't think you can do what you're asking. The width 100% will always refer to the width of the container.

Comment: Try giving the value of width more than 900px of the header.

Comment: But I want it to be like, infinite.

Comment: Try 200% width. I am not sure but try it out.

Comment: You can do one thing. Make an image that will look like the type of header you want and then put it in the header div. And set it to repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute positioning. The header element would then be sized and positioned according to the nearest parent who has `position: relative;` defined (which by default is the `<body>` element). Like so:

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0; /* it will span from the left to the right edges */
    height: 100px; /* it helps to set a fixed-sized height too, but this isn't required */
}
```

Comment: @Rogustus That may be because your `#Container` is also positioned relative so it is still calculating 100% of that container. Remove the relative position on `#Container` and see if that works